# Calling a soap web service using java

Tags: java, soap

In my java program, I need to call a SOAP web service that is deployed on a remote server.

Looks like there are several different approaches when explored in web. 
But I would like to know as what is currently being used more in the developer world.

Also is there is a way to call a SOAP web service using Spring or axis or xfire.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585842/whats-the-best-and-most-comprehencive-soap-library-available-with-relation-to-que

Answer (score 1):

For spring you can look at http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html for client information.

When I write SOAP webservices I tend to use jax-ws now, especially since it comes installed with JDK6 now.

For a tutorial on that you can look at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS.html.

I like it since it uses annotations, so is simpler than using axis.

If you are using Spring then using their webservice options would be your best bet though.